# Put some values on internet to access from android

Tags: android, xml, web, web-hosting

In my app a user can (only) see the values uploaded by admin. 
For example. A salesman is using the app will be able to see the latest rate provided by the manger to trade.
Now the question is "where to put these values?" 
I have .net webservice experience with android but I guess it wont work in this scenario,will it?
Any suggestion that the returned result be in (preferably) XML format.

Comment: do you have a solution to your problem?

Comment: Not yet parse.com seems to be good but not what i needed

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you already know how to do this. [You can download and parse xml](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html) within your app. If you alreayd know how to set up the websever, the rest is easy. Limiting who can see what is just a matter of associating specific transactions with an individuals account. Then just have the phone check for updates on that transaction when the app loads (using someting like `AsyncTask`) or if you want to get more complicated you could push notificatinos using the android cloud service, or even use a `REST` model. More details are needed for a more specific answer but you can do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on your own, and build a webserver with a MySQL/PHP JSON API or you can use parse.com for a smaller project.